How can I deserialize JSON into totally different types from the same JSON dictionary or array without a custom deserializer?
How can I deserialize JSON into different types from the same JSON dictionary?
I have to deserialize data from JSON into C# that can be many different types in a JSON dictionary, for example:
{
    "KEY1": { "mainType": "TYPE1", /* object of a specific type */ },
    "KEY2": { "mainType": "TYPE2", /* object of a similar but different type */ },
    "KEY3": { "mainType": "TYPE3", /* object of a very different type */ },
    "KEY4": { "mainType": "TYPE4", /* yet another completely different type */ },
    "KEY4": { "mainType": "TYPE5", /* another totally different type.... why? */ }
}

Where all these different types have completely different properties and the mainType property tells us which type is the correct type to deserialize.
I don't want to write a custom serializer, I would rather let System.Text.Json do it for me.
I was able to answer my own question and wanted to write it down for others (see below):

Here is some sample System.Text.Json C# that solves this problem (using .NET 7+):
First, create a base type all the other will inherit from, it's okay if they don't share any properties:
public class BaseType 
{
    // any shared properties
}

Next create all the child types:
public class Type1 : BaseType 
{ 
    // custom properties...
}
public class Type2 : BaseType 
{ }
public class Type3 : BaseType 
{ }
// ...etc

Next, we need to tell System.Text.Json what the derived types will be when deserializing.  Add the following attribute to the base class so System.Text.Json will know what types to deserialize to:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Type1), typeDiscriminator:"TYPE1")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Type2), typeDiscriminator:"TYPE2")]
// ...etc
public class BaseType 
{
    ...
}

In my case, the type discriminator was not a normal type discriminator name like "$type" so I had to tell System.Text.Json what type discriminator property name to use by adding this attribute:
[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "mainType")]
public class BaseType 

In order to deserialize the full dictionary, I used this code:
using System.Text.Json;

var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var dictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize< Dictionary<string, BaseType> >(json);


Good self-answered question
